# SerialPort read just first character of string

Tags: c#, serial-port

I create small test app to test connection between app and some device which measure temperature. When I write some command to device it's ok, but when device return me response, a string, for that I use ReadExisting() method. But app reads just first character of the string. If I send command again, it's same situation. I try to test connection with program called Terminal.exe, it's happens the same. But when I change BaudRate at some value and return BaudRate on 9600 ( it's ok rate ), then it's worked fine. Also I try to change BaudRate in my app, but it give me the same, just first character of string. Also I have an app written in LabView which works fine.

Also I tested my app with another PC with Terminal.exe , and it's worked fine.

```
private void SetUpPort()
    {
        port = new SerialPort();
        port.PortName = port_name;
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
        p.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(PortDataReceived);
    }
private void PortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        recived_data += port.ReadExisting();
    }
```

I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: I found solution, `port.DtrEnable` property was `false`. It's should be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how to use the `SerialPort` component. You need to attach the [`DataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler, which is called every time data comes in on the serial port. An example is found on the page I linked.

---

You need to append data until you know you're done! You can't just call `ReadExisting` and assume you get all the information. Do something like this:

```
private string inBuffer = String.Empty;

private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

    inBuffer += indata;
    if (<inBuffer fulfills some criteria that tells you it's a complete message>)
    {
        ProcessInBuffer(inBuffer);
        inBuffer = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

It is *your* task to determine the criteria to fulfill. This may be that the received data as a certain length (if the records are fixed length), or maybe they end with newline characters or something else.

Comment: I now, I didn't post whole code, it's just one line. Sorry about that. I will edit my post.

Comment: If that is the code, then how do you make sure that you have received the entire message? Each call to `DataReceived` gives you a part of the data. You need to know when it's over and you can not assume to get all the data in the first call to `ReadExisting`.

Comment: I know because data is like "S1 11:21:15 28.11.2013 24.5C". And I always get S, which is first character of string. I've been tested app with another PC using Terminal.exe to send data to my app. And then app receive all string.

Comment: Well, maybe the device is just slower than the other PC using Terminal.exe? What you don't seem to grasp is that in your code I can't see anything that determines if you actually *have* received all data and keeps appending until done!

Comment: I don't think that device is slow. As I know, DataReceived event is automatically fired when device send data. So, all data should be received. Also, it's interesting that when I start Terminal.exe to recive data from device it wont work but when I change BaudRate to some different value and change back to 9600 then it work. Before changing BaudRate is same as with my app.

Comment: And that's where you are wrong! You may **not** receive all data in `DataReceived`. And guess what? You don't! That's the entire point of your question, so why don't you just do what I suggest or at least write some test client that just outputs to the console what it reads from the serial port as in the Microsoft sample? Then you can actually **see** what's happening. By the way, the problem can also arise if the two devices use different BAUD rate. Make sure they use the same.

Comment: OK, I will try this. I can test app with device tomorrow, so when I do test, I will write comment. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It's not that the device is slow, it's that it's communicating on an incredibly slow link relative to the PC - the PC can execute literally millions of instructions between each received char.  So from the point of view of the receiver, there is an age between each char.

Comment: @WillDean Yes, what I was trying to say is that from the application's point of view data is coming in slowly, even though the device itself may send the data within milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

you will use datareceived event to store all the data in a array or string and after you can use every data of that string indata += sp.ReadExisting();

Comment: Yes, but when I tested app with other PC on which is running Terminal.exe which I use to send data to my app, it worked. App receive whole string in one part. And with device it wont work. Just first character of string.